# Angular/Testing unit: Failed: The pipe 'async' could not be found

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

When I run the `ng test` on this spec file it fail with this error:

#### Failed: The pipe 'async' could not be found!

I have tried to `fakesync()` the test and still the same

```js
describe('ProductSinglePage', () => {
  let component: ProductSinglePage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductSinglePage>;
  let store: MockStore;
  const initialState = { keyvalue: false };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProductFormPage],
      imports: [CommonModule, RouterTestingModule, IonicModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({
          initialState,
          selectors: [
            {
              selector: getProductById,
              value: 1
            }
          ]
        }),
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductSinglePage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));
  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  it('should create',  () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Very Simple Html

```html
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let product of (product$ | async) ">
      <ion-label> <b>{{product.key}}</b> : <b>{{product.value}}</b></ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Very Simple ts file used NGRX

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-single',
  templateUrl: './product-single.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-single.page.scss'],
})
export class ProductSinglePage implements OnInit {
  product$: Observable<ProductInterface>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.product$ = this.store.select(getProductById);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking that the testing unit has an error, but actually, the HTML was not right

it passes the test after removed `async` from the HTML `ngFor`

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let product of product$ ">
      <ion-label> <b>{{product.key}}</b> : <b>{{product.value}}</b></ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

The message:

The pipe 'async' could not be found

Probably refers to your use of observable$ | async in your HTML

This probably relates to you failing to import the correct modules in your spec file.

My advice is, just import the module you are working on itself inside the spec file and not individual modules (unless they are root level, in which case they will need to be imported) and that should work. Also, if you import the module you are working on and the component you are testing is declared in that module then you will need to remove the component declaration from your spec file.

Comment: This is what the problem is.  The answer above is changing how the data is initialized for the component, but then you need to unsubscribe from the subscription.  Async pipe makes it so you do not have to unsubscribe.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing a similar issue, in my case, I was using the `ngrxPush`pipe.

> The pipe 'ngrxPush' could not be found!

The issue was persisting even though I've imported the correct module i.e. `ReactiveComponentModule` which contains the `ngrxPush`in `spec.ts` file.

In my case, the error got resolved when I fixed the mockStore's config(added the missing `initialState` attribute).

```
  providers: [
    provideMockStore(
      {
        initialState: {
          changePassword: false
        }
      })
  ]
```

I believe the stack trace provided by Angular is misleading.